# Why does calling the timeout program from a bash script cause tcsetattr to hang?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, timeout

For some reason calling the timeout program, giving the program which has tcsetattr inside as an argument, from a bash script causes tcsetattr to hang. Calling it outside of the bash script directly in the terminal doesn't cause it to hang. Why does this happen? Looking at https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/timeout.c, it doesn't seem like timeout messes with any file descriptors. It looks like it is set up to ignore two signals but that shouldn't be relevant here.

The following is a minimal test case:

short.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        struct termios tty;
        tcgetattr(0, &tty);
        fprintf(stderr, "Before tcsetattr");
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tty);
        fprintf(stderr, "After tcsetattr");
}
```

simple_check.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 5 ./a.out < /dev/tty
echo $?
```

Bash output

```
$ gcc short.c
$ bash simple_check.sh
Before tcsetattr
124 # Note this should output `After tcsetattr` if it was 'working'
$ timeout 5 ./a.out < /dev/tty
Before tcsetattr
After tcsetattr
```

Potentially useful information

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Works without any issues on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.

Comment: As in `bash simple_check.sh` outputs Before tcsetattr
After tcsetattr ? @codeforester

Comment: That does hang!  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Isn't it baffling lol?

Comment: It is.  `bash simple_check.sh < /dev/null` works and so does `nohup ...`

Comment: Because `timeout` (without the `--foreground` flag) creates a new process group, `a.out`'s process group ID ([`getpgrp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpgrp.2.html)) will not match its terminal group ID [`tcgetpgrp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcgetpgrp.3.html)), `a.out` is a background process. When a background process issues the `tcsetattr()` to the controlling terminal, it gets stopped by the `SIGTTOU` signal. To avoid this, run `timeout --foreground 5 ./a.out` (for a single process), or `timeout 5 setsid ./a.out` (process group, but no controlling terminal).

Comment: @NominalAnimal Ahh that makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--foreground` option to timeout might avoid this issue?
That stops putting the timeout (and children) into their own program group.

Comment: RHEL 6's timeout doesn't have a --foreground option. Are there other workarounds?